# How to append an entered Social Security number to xxx-xx-1111?

Tags: java, append, tostring

I am learning Java and am working on a program for a class. I've completed the bulk of the program so not much help is needed.

How can I convert a SSN (entered by scanner) from, 111-11-1111 to xxx-xx-1111?

I also need to validate that the format of the numbers entered is correct. There is a main class and an Astronaut class where I have getters and setters for the SSN. I already have a `toString` override method to format it the way I want when I run the program.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    super.toString();
    System.out.println("SSN: " + ssn);
    return "";
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `super.toString()` to achieve?

Comment: Aside from main question: `toString()` shouldn't be responsible for *printing* anything, but generating String representation of an object *which* then can be used as client want, for instance it can be printed. Using that logic your `super.toString()` would be redundant because it would return some value which you are ignoring. If your superclass really generates values which you want to also print along with your Astronaut then you probably wanted something like `String parentStr = super.toString(); ...; return parentStr+other+elements;`

Comment: Anyway easiest way to replacing single characters with other characters would be converting string to char[], modifying that char[], and creating `new String(modifiedCharArray)`. You could also use substring method to get only part which you are interested in and concatenate it with mask.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the Astronaut is an extension of another class

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SSN: XXX-XX-" + ssn.substring(7);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to validate that the number of digits entered is correct, you can use a regex expression. For example: `ssn.matches("(\\d-)?\\d{3}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")`